# How to disable Meltdown and Spectre patches in Centos 6?

Tags: centos6, kernel, linux-kernel

I wondering how you can disable the Meltdown/Spectre patches in Centos 6?

Various tutorials refers to Grub2 and recompiling, but in Centos 6, I do not have this.

I can edit the grub.conf file in `/boot/grub` directory

I have ran the command `for f in /sys/devices/system/cpu/vulnerabilities/*; do echo "${f##*/} -" $(cat "$f"); done`

which outputs:

```
meltdown - Mitigation: PTI
spectre_v1 - Mitigation: Load fences
spectre_v2 - Mitigation: Full retpoline
```

The kernel version is: `2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64`

In ubuntu and grub2, it refers to updating `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=`, but I believe this is GRUB2.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In /boot/grub/grub.conf, on your kernel line(s), add:
mitigations=off